# Angular 6 Interceptor not working as expected

Tags: angular6, angular-http-interceptors

I have written an `Http Interceptor` in Angular 6 . 
The goal is to reload the home page when `302 status` is returned. (any back end API returning 302 status )
I am currently not able to understand why the `Interceptor` is behaving the way it is.

**Below is the code  :**

```
@Injectable()
export class ResponseHandler implements HttpInterceptor{


    constructor(){

    }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {


     return next.handle(request).pipe(


            map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {

                if(event instanceof HttpResponse){
                    if(event.status === 302){
                        console.log('HttpResponse 302 status ');
                        window.location.reload();
                        return EMPTY;
                    }
                }

            })
        )

    }

}
```

**Actual Behaviour :**

1)I am first accessing the home page explicitly. `(e.g: /home)`

2)But the strange thing is , the initial call to fetch home age itself is not happening

3)It seems request is blocked reaching the server.

4)When interceptor is removed , this initial call is happening `(/home)`

I am not able to understand why is this behaviour ?

Why the request is getting blocked as I am **NOT tampering** with request it should be passed as is to back end rest end point .

It should be intercepted only when `HttpResponse` is returned with `302 error` code .

Can anybody please help here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you forgot to return value in map operator. The main goal of map operator is to modify data and **RETURN** it back.

```
         map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {

            if(event instanceof HttpResponse){
                if(event.status === 302){
                    console.log('HttpResponse 302 status ');
                    window.location.reload();
                    return EMPTY;
                }
            }

            return event;  // here you return value back
        })
```

Comment: Hi Dmitriy , It was right . Returning event from map operator resolved the issue